# Setting <access> whitelist on Config.xml corrupted

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am having problem with setting  elements for whitelisting protocols.  Following directions from [Cordova Whitelist Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide), under External Application Whitelist, I am setting the  tag with launch-external attribute to allow phone numbers to request the dialer:

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

However, if I open the config.xml helper window, say to update versionCode or build number, the launch-external attribute is silently lost. Consequently, the subsequent build looks ok, all the way to the users device, where tapping the phone number causes the app to crash.

I don't see these whitelist entries in AndroidManifest.xml, so I can't use the platform override to inject these there.  Is there somewhere else I should be putting these  elements?

Comment: Can you explain how do you add the access line to the config.xml and how do you change the versionCode or build number?

Comment: @jcesarmobile: I add the access line by editing the config.xml directly, by right-click on config.xml in Solution Explorer, then View Code.

I edited the versionCode and build number by using the config.xml helper window (or whatever its called) by double left-clicking on the config.xml in Solution Explorer.

Comment: can't you add the access line from that helper window?

Comment: @jcesarmobile: Not with the launch-external attribute, no.  The helper window only has an entry for the URI (origin) entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova team with this issue. They replied today that this will be fixed in an upcoming release, and that they do not have any workarounds at this time.

So, for time being, I will just need to be careful and check the access tags before each Android build.